# Select top N with joins

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to join 2 tables with top n results of other table as explained below.

OrderHeader

```
OH_Id        OrderDate
----------------------
1            2014-06-01
2            2014-06-02
3            2014-06-03
4            2014-06-04
5            2014-06-05
```

OrderProducts

```
OP_Id        OH_Id    Quantity
------------------------------
1              1       1
2              1       2
3              2       1
4              3       3
5              4       4
6              4       1
7              4       2
8              5       2
9              5       1
```

I am expecting result something like this for top 3 orders (4 rows).

```
OH_Id        OrderDate       Op_Id      Quantity
------------------------------------------------
1            2014-06-01      1           1
1            2014-06-01      2           2
2            2014-06-02      3           1
3            2014-06-03      4           3
```

Note: I am looking specifically to join 2 tables rather writing as SP or looped queries.

Comment: first things first. Are you using sql server or mysql ?

Comment: you want the first 3 order numbers from `OrderHeader` with all corresponding rows from `OrderProducts`?

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 3 o.oh_id, o.orderdate, oo.op_id, oo.quantity
from orderheader o 
join orderproducts oo on o.oh_id = oo.oh_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This query gives only 3 rows, whereas I am expecting 4 rows with top 3 orders.

Comment: change to top 4 and order by clause at the end

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first 3 order numbers from OrderHeader with all corresponding rows from OrderProducts try this.

```
select o.oh_id
    ,o.orderdate
    ,oo.op_id
    ,oo.quantity
from (SELECT TOP 3  * 
      FROM orderheader 
      ORDER BY OH_ID --or Date etc...
     ) o 
INNER JOIN orderproducts oo 
    on o.oh_id = oo.oh_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your description is confusing. You don't want top 3 as that will return only 3 rows. You just want ids 1-3 from what it sounds like.

```
SELECT * 
FROM OrderHeader a
JOIN OrderHeader b on a.oh_id = b.oh_id
WHERE a.oh_id <= 3
```

Comment: what if the first order number in the table is 4?

Comment: Not exactly sure about the question

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a sub query like this

```
SELECT * FROM OrderHeader 
INNER JOIN OrderProducts ON OrderHeader.OH_Id = OrderProducts.OH_Id
WHERE OrderHeader.OH_Id IN (SELECT TOP 3 OH_Id FROM OrderHeader)
```

A test sql fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78e22/4)

hope this helps